# Custom context manager is left when running pdb.set_trace()

Tags: python, pdb, contextmanager

I have noticed that running `pdb.set_trace()` or `ipdb.set_trace()` as the last line of a context, its context manager and the variable assigned by it are already destroyed.

Peculiarly, when doing the same with Python's builtin `open()`, this is not the case.

```
import pdb
import contextlib


@contextlib.contextmanager
def my_open(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        yield f


class my_open_class():
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.filename = filename

    def __enter__(self):
        self.f = open(self.filename)
        return self.f

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback):
        self.f.close()


with open("/dev/null") as f:
    # f will be available
    pdb.set_trace()


with my_open("/dev/null") as f:
    # f will not be available!
    pdb.set_trace()


with my_open_class("/dev/null") as f:
    # f will not be available!
    pdb.set_trace()


with my_open("/dev/null") as f:
    # f will be available!
    pdb.set_trace()
    pass


with my_open_class("/dev/null") as f:
    # f will be available!
    pdb.set_trace()
    pass
```

When running and stepping through the code (use `c` to continue from first to second breakpoint), the prompt is different, too:

The first block stops when entering the context at `open(...)`

```
> /Users/me/test.py(28)<module>()
-> with my_open("/dev/null") as f:
```

While the second and third block stop when leaving the context at `__exit__(...)`

```
(Pdb) c
--Call--
> /usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/contextlib.py(86)__exit__()
-> def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
(Pdb) c
--Call--
> /Users/me/test.py(19)__exit__()
-> def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback):
```

And the fourth and fifth block stop at `pass`:

```
(Pdb) c
> /Users/me/test.py(41)<module>()
-> pass
(Pdb) c
> /Users/me/test.py(47)<module>()
-> pass
(Pdb) c
```

I cannot find a reason for this behaviour, and cannot believe this is on purpose.

Is this a bug in Python or pdb? Is there a way to circumvent this without adding a `pass`?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? in `__enter__(self)` you should return `self.f` .

Comment: I am trying to set a breakpoint at the last line of a context, without losing data from that context. I have fixed the returnvalue in `__enter__`.

Comment: i tried the class way..it os working fine for me...i can access `self.f` just before exit

Comment: I am trying to access `f`, in the scope of where I called `pdb.set_trace()`

Comment: Yes I was able to do that